# Azure DB - How to give 1 user read-only permission for 1 table

Tags: sql-server, azure

I've been reading many answers but I am too weak at TSQL to filter out what I need.

I created a *contained* user for 1 DB...

```
CREATE USER appuser WITH PASSWORD = 'strongpwd';
```

So I need to allow a user in to read only the contents of 1 table - tableA (there are others in the DB) and do absolutely nothing else in the DB.

I do not want to affect any other users. I just want the user to be able to access the DB via say SSMS, see only tableA (well this is not that important), read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways one is to directly grant explicit SELECT only on Table 1 and the second one is to create a role, grant SELECT to role and addd the user to the role. Typically second way is the preferred way and can be done as below

CREATE ROLE [role_name]

GRANT SELECT ON [Table] to [role_name]

EXEC sp_addrolemember '[role_name]', 'appuser'